# how to print the contents of an iframe using dart?

Tags: dart

The dart version of contentWindow does not have a print method.
If printing directly from dart is not possible, how could I use regular javascript to print an iframe using js interop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `dart:js` this should work:

```
import 'dart:js';
...
final iframe = querySelector('iframe') as IFrameElement;
(new JsObject.fromBrowserObject(iframe)['contentWindow']['print'] as JsFunction).apply(<dynamic>[]);
```

With `package:js`

```
@JS()
library maps;

@JS('document.querySelector')
external JsWindow query(String selector);

@JS("Window")
class JsWindow {
  external JsWindow get contentWindow;
  external void print();
}

query('iframe').contentWindow.print();
```